# "compile on save" doesn't work on my Angular project

Tags: angular, typescript

I created (Yesterday) a new angular project by cli (ng new my-app) .. but the option "compile on save" doesn't work on my project ! I should be noted that i have two project on my PC, and "auto compile" works correctly for one of them and doesn't work for another

- now the first project (healthy) is stoped and i'm trying on the other (who has problem)
- I changed port of the project's but it doesn't work again
- I work with updated visual studio 2017
- "compileOnSave" option is true

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

wow !
I found the answer from [this link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2389) ..
path of the project had **space** character !

Answer (score -1):

You can only run one project at a time. Unless you change the port.

## More

Check the docs https://angular.io/

Comment: now the first project (healthy) is stoped and i'm trying on the other (who has problem) ..